# jfreechart put abitrary text inside bars in a stacked bargraph

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I have a horizontal stacked barchart with a dynamic number of "sub"-bars per row (number depending on data input to my program) in the chart. I would like to name the sub-bars in some way, preferably with text inside the bars. The different rows in the chart are independent. Is this possible?

An example: Row one contains 5 bars that get the labels "A", "B", "C", "D" and "E" while row two has 2 bars with the name "F" and "G".

There isn't a way to attach text in the dataset, I guess?

Thanks!

A example picture of the current graph:

[link to chart picture](http://i1025.photobucket.com/albums/y316/tjek1/THREAD2_0_zps66948249.png)

Here is some code how it looks today:

```
public void plot(Formatter formatter) {
    boolean functionsFound;
    int level = 0;
    // create the dataset...
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    int offset;
    double d;

    do {
        functionsFound = false;
        offset = startTime;
        for (FunctionInstance x : functionInstances) {
            if (x.getOvlLevel() == level) {
                functionsFound = true;
                dataset.addValue(d = (double)(x.getFuncExecTimeStart() - x.getPreOverhead() - offset), "- " + Integer.toString(offset), "Level: " + Integer.toString(level));
                dataset.addValue(d = (double)x.getPreOverhead(), "pre overhead " + Integer.toString(offset), "Level: " + Integer.toString(level));
                dataset.addValue(d = (double)x.getFuncExecTime(), "func exec " + Integer.toString(offset), "Level: " + Integer.toString(level));
                dataset.addValue(d = (double)x.getPostOverhead(), "post overhead " + Integer.toString(offset), "Level: " + Integer.toString(level));
                offset = x.getFuncExecTimeStart() + x.getFuncExecTime() + x.getPostOverhead();
            }
        }
        level++;
    } while (functionsFound);

     // create the chart...
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
        "Function hierarchy", 
        "Level",                    // domain axis label
        "Cycles",                   // range axis label
        dataset,                    // data
        PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, // orientation
        false,                      // include legend
        true,                       // tooltips?
        false                       // URLs?
    );

    // set the background color for the chart...
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    chart.getTitle().setMargin(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

    LegendItemCollection items = new LegendItemCollection();
    items.add(new LegendItem("Function execution", null, null, null, 
            new Rectangle2D.Double(-6.0, -3.0, 12.0, 6.0), Color.green));
    items.add(new LegendItem("Overhead", null, null, null, 
            new Rectangle2D.Double(-6.0, -3.0, 12.0, 6.0), Color.red));
    plot.setFixedLegendItems(items);
    plot.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(5, 5, 5, 20));
    LegendTitle legend = new LegendTitle(plot);
    legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
    chart.addSubtitle(legend);

    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    // set the range axis to display integers only...
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0);

    // disable bar outlines...
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);

    // set up gradient paints for series...
    Paint gp0 = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.red, 
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(64, 0, 0));
    GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.green, 
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0, 64, 0));
    GradientPaint gp3 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.red, 
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(64, 0, 0));
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(y*4 + 0, gp0);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(y*4 + 1, gp1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(y*4 + 2, gp2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(y*4 + 3, gp3);
    }

    ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
    BufferedImage img = chart.createBufferedImage(1000, 500, info);

    try {
        OutputStream ost =
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(Global.tempFileDirectory + "/" + thrInstName + ".png"), false));
        ChartUtilities.writeBufferedImageAsPNG(ost, img);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some code piece which we can verify?

Comment: added code and a picture (link)